# Error on Displaying attribute

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to display one of the 'Estimated Hours Remaining' attribute of 'Project' in a new page called 'Appointments'. 
[image]

So, I created an unbound field name 'ProjectEstimatedRemainingHours'. Then customized attribute of the field like this:

```
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PM;
[PXString(40)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Project Estimated Remaining Hours")]
[PXDBScalar(
typeof(Search<PMProject.productCD,
Where<PMProject.productID, Equal<FSServiceOrder.productID>>>))]
```

> I was trying to see if I can get any property of 'Project' first.

But then, I encountered the following error:

[image]

The weird part is even if I unpublish or even remove the customize project on which I was making this change, this error persists.

I need help to get the 'Estimated Remaining Hours' attribute of 'Project' without getting error.

Comment: "The weird part is even if I unpublish or even remove the customize project on which I was making this change, this error persists." try to clear your cache and project assemblies. Could you include the trace in the question?

Comment: I cleared the cache(even tried on different browser) then rebuild the solution too. I didn't find any stack trace(I guess the trace you mean is the stack trace.). Problem is still there.

Comment: Use the menu Help > trace on your right top

Comment: Got it. Here is the trace. 
http://www.screencast.com/t/KPv1F1pGC

Comment: Did you try removing *all* customization projects? This type of error usually occur when a customization declares a DAC field that has a different type from the one in the database or when a BQL request clause resolves to a type mismatch.

Comment: Actually, I already had try removing the last customization from where the error started occurring. But, I again removed all the customizations and problem still persists. Talking about change on DAC field, here is one change, which I believe has nothing to do with the type.
http://www.screencast.com/t/wRLq5WmIk

And this was the BQL I wrote which I had removed already.

`[PXDBScalar(`
`typeof(Search<PMProject.productCD,`
`Where<PMProject.productID, Equal<FSServiceOrder.productID>>>))]`